# How this json string updation can be done in java?

Tags: java, json

I have to return a json string from java but the json will be update via multiple method calls. Say ex i have this format,

```
{
   "empl0yee":[
      {
         "roleNo":"0",
         "sem1":[{
            // Values will be updated by method1
         }
         ],
         "emplyeeDetails":[{
           // Values will be updated by method2
          }
         ]
       }
      ]
}
```

I have to update this json string across various method calls how can i do it in java? Will the method1 values be retained when method2 is called to set the value?

Comment: I think, that's the question on JSON tools, so it is off-topic, isn't it?

Comment: Show us the code you have tried.

Comment: why not have a final employee shared across classes and update the contents of the object. Then after all the updation is done, then convert it into JSON and persist it.

Comment: For reference, updation is not a word.

Comment: Could you post your Java code (method1 & method2)? Do you have an Employee class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a json-(de)serializer library, like [Google GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

As you receive your json data block, deserialize it to a java object.

Then update your java object. And when it is done, serialize this object to a json-string.

Check this GSON user guide: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide